# MS Access VBA SQL query runs, but does not Insert

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to make an MS Access application, fairly new to VBA but used to MySQL. The problem I am having is that I am trying to insert values to a table, the code runs without giving an error but the table does not update. Can anyone help?

I am mainly having an issue with this line:

```vb
 db.Execute ("INSERT INTO Transaction ([TranDate], TranItem365, TranAmount, TranOperation) VALUES ( #" & Now() & "# , " & txtTranItem365.Value & ", " & txtTranAmount.Value & ", '" & txtTranOperation.Value & "')")
```

---

Here is the full code for context.

```vb
Private Sub btnApplyTransaction_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim sql As String
Dim oper As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

If txtTranItem365.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Please select an item.", vbCritical
ElseIf txtTranAmount.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an amount.", vbCritical
ElseIf txtTranOperation.Value = "Issue" And txtIssuedToDept.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Please select a department to issue to.", vbCritical
Else:


    sql = DLookup("[ItmStock]", "Items", "[Itm365]=" & txtTranItem365.Value)

    oper = "+"

    If txtTranOperation.Value = "Issue" Then
        oper = "-"
    End If

    db.Execute ("Update Items set ItmStock = (" & sql & oper & txtTranAmount & ") where Itm365=" & txtTranItem365.Value)
    db.Execute ("INSERT INTO Transaction ([TranDate], TranItem365, TranAmount, TranOperation) VALUES ( #" & Now() & "# , " & txtTranItem365.Value & ", " & txtTranAmount.Value & ", '" & txtTranOperation.Value & "')")
    If txtTranOperation.Value = "Issue" Then
        sql = "32"
        MsgBox "INSERT INTO Issueance values (" & sql & ", " & txtIssuedToDept.Value & ", " & txtIssuedTo.Value & ")"
        db.Execute ("INSERT INTO Issueance values (" & sql & ", " & txtIssuedToDept.Value & ", '" & txtIssuedTo.Value & "')")
    End If

    txtTranAmount.Value = ""
    txtTranItem365 = ""
    txtTranOperation = "Add"
    txtIssuedTo = ""
    txtIssuedToDept = ""
    DoCmd.RefreshRecord
    db.Close

End If
```

More Context:
TranDate is Date+Time, essentialy Now() function.
TranItem365 is a number.
TranAmount is a number.
TranOperation is ["Add", "Issue"].

Comment: Everything looks ok. Few things to try. Try making your Database explicitly DAO, by changing this `dim db as DAO.Database`. Also, Access can sometimes by finicky with field names. To be sure it isn't an issue, surround all your fields with `[]`. What happens if you try to manually run this insert with Access in a new query window?

Comment: Building on @RyanWildry :  put that query into a string variable. set a breakpoint, grab a copy of the contents of the string, then try to run the query in a query window. You should get some diagnostic.

Comment: Update, Tried [], didn't help. Tried running it in Query Window actually gave a hint, "didnt add 1 record due to key violations"

Comment: There you go! Well done.

Comment: The second INSERT is not valid syntax. So once you get past the first, will have another error. Table 'Issueance` name is a misspelling, but I assume this is the actual table name regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resolving the integrity violation issue from your table definition, please consider parameterized queries using MS Access [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao) for a more readable and maintainable workflow.

It helps separate SQL from VBA to avoid messy, hard to read, error-prone concatenation and quote enclosures. Additionally, use pure SQL as your `DLookUp` is unnecessary with the `If` block and `Now()` is available in queries.

**SQL Update** Query *(save as query object, adjust data types as needed)*

```sql
PARAMETERS txtTranAmountParam Double, txtTranOperationParam Text, txtTranItem365Param Long;
UPDATE [Items] 
SET ItmStock = IIF([txtTranOperationParam] = 'Issue',
                   ItmStock - [txtTranAmountParam],
                   ItmStock + [txtTranAmountParam])
WHERE Itm365 = txtTranItem365Param;
```

**SQL Append** Query  *(save as query object, adjust data types as needed)*

```sql
PARAMETERS txtTranAmountParam Double, txtTranOperationParam Text, txtTranItem365Param Long;
INSERT INTO Transaction ([TranDate], TranItem365, TranAmount, TranOperation) 
VALUES (Now(), [txtTranItem365Param], [txtTranAmountParam], [txtTranOperationParam]);
```

**SQL Append** Query  *(save as query object, adjust data types as needed)*

```sql
PARAMETERS SQLParam Long, txtIssuedToDeptParam Long, txtIssuedToParam Long;
INSERT INTO Issueance VALUES ([SQLParam], [txtIssuedToDeptParam], [txtIssuedToParam])
```

**VBA** *(referencing above query objects)*

```vb
Private Sub btnApplyTransaction_Click()

   Dim db As Database
   Dim upd_qdef As QueryDef, apn_qdef As QueryDef, iss_qdef As QueryDef
   Dim sql As String, oper As String

   Set db = CurrentDb()

   If txtTranItem365.ListIndex = -1 Then
       MsgBox "Please select an item.", vbCritical
       Exit Sub 
   End If
   If txtTranAmount.Value = "" Then
       MsgBox "Please enter an amount.", vbCritical
       Exit Sub 
   End If
   If txtTranOperation.Value = "Issue" And txtIssuedToDept.ListIndex = -1 Then
       MsgBox "Please select a department to issue to.", vbCritical
       Exit Sub 
   End If

   ' ASSIGN QUERYDEFS, BIND PARAMS, AND EXECUTE ACTION
   ' UPDATE
   Set upd_qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedUpdateQuery")
   upd_qdef!txtTranAmountParam = txtTranAmount
   upd_qdef!txtTranOperationParam = txtTranOperation.Value
   upd_qdef!txtTranItem365Param = txtTranItem365.Value

   upd_qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

   ' APPEND
   Set apn_qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedAppendQuery")
   apn_qdef!txtTranAmountParam = txtTranAmount
   apn_qdef!txtTranOperationParam = txtTranOperation.Value
   apn_qdef!txtTranItem365Param = txtTranItem365.Value

   apn_qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

   If txtTranOperation.Value = "Issue" Then
        Set iss_qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedIssueanceAppendQuery")

        iss_qdef!SQLParam = 32
        iss_qdef!txtIssuedToDeptParam = txtIssuedToDept.Value
        iss_qdef!txtIssuedToDeptParam = txtIssuedTo.Value

        iss_qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
   End If

   txtTranAmount.Value = "": txtTranItem365 = "": txtTranOperation = "Add"
   txtIssuedTo = "": txtIssuedToDept = ""

   DoCmd.RefreshRecord

   Set upd_qdef = Nothing: apn_qdef = Nothing: iss_qdef = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing    
End If
```

Comment: That actually helped, as said before I am new to VBA so you did add somethings that I was looking for. The Query Windows Did help out to isolate the real problem, turns out, it was only accepting Item.ID instead of Item.Item365ID which doesn't make sense. Oh well thanks